# How to use DataGrip SQL formatter with UNLOAD statement

Tags: sql, formatting, amazon-redshift, jetbrains-ide, datagrip

If I have some Redshift `UNLOAD` statement such as:

```sql
unload ('select * from table')
to 's3://bucket/file.csv.gz'
iam_role 'credential_string'
gzip csv allowoverwrite;
```

the DataGrip SQL formatter will inline the whole thing like this:

```sql
unload ('select * from table') to 's3://bucket/file.csv.gz' iam_role 'credential_string' gzip csv allowoverwrite;
```

Is there a SQL formatting configuration I can make to prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no option of that kind.

Please file a feature request: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/DBE